# What was the name of the Master Namer in the Wizard of Earthsea books and how do you pronounce it?

Tags: ursula-k-le-guin, earthsea, pronunciation

What was the name of the Master Namer in the Wizard of Earthsea books and how do you pronounce it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kurremkarmerruk; cur-əm-**car**-mər-uhk.

Comment: And note that this is the name of each Master Namer: the name goes with the job. As I recall, his previous use name was not mentioned.

Comment: I believe you're correct so I assume it's not his true name. Unless you can change your true name which sounds... awful

Comment: @GordonBennett I believe a person's true name _can_ be changed. In 'The Farthest Shore' Ged gives the dyer woman Akaren on Lorbanery a new name to release her from the torment brought on by the disappearance of magic from her world. After re-naming her mind is quiet but she no longer recognises her son and he no longer recognises her as the same person -- she's fundamentally altered by the process.